# what happens if mkdir() goes through a path that exists

Tags: php, database

I was wondering what would happen if mkdir() went through a path that already exists

```
idfolder=$_SESSION['cpuserid'];

         $dir="../uploads/articles/".$idfolder;

         if(!file_exists($dir)){
         //user has'nt tried posting an article
         mkdir($dir);
         else{
         //user already made an article

                    //article id will be retrieved to make folder 
                    $sql_retrievefolderid=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(article_id) FROM cp_article");
                    //will make a folder named by the article id and 
                    //is assumed that it is the latest(max) id. 

                    $dir_articleid=$dir."/".$sql_retrievefolderid;

                    mkdir($dir_articleid)
```

I know that mkdir() is capable of making a folder but what if I go through a path that is already made would it overwrite the contents of the existing folders?

Comment: trying it would have been faster then writing a question, but no, it won't overwrite the existing folders

Answer (score 0):

Nothing would happen. It would not override a path that already exists or and the files inside that folder, instead it would just print a error like this:

```
Warning: mkdir(): File exists in "your path"
```

More info about `mkdir()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).